# Push from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a tricky situation. The following is the hierarchy of the views that I have.

```
(Root)Navigation-VC-->View A-->(via Segue push)--> View B-->View C
(Root)Navigation-VC-->View A-->(via modal push)-->(Nav Controller) View D-->View E
```

There is a cancel button in view D. When I click on it, it correctly shows view A. But For some reasons I would want it to go to View B in the first navigation hierarchy. How can I do such transitions?

If I create a modal segue from view D to view B it destroys the navigation hierarchy that view B is part of. If I push view B from view D then view B becomes a part of a different hierarchy altogether.

Can it be done? Do I have to rethink the design?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you dismiss the modal view controller, you can always call the method performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: to push view B. Just remember to set the segue identifier in your storyboard.

Call the method dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: in view A and call the perform segue at the completion block. This is just to avoid any corruption that might happen to the navigation controller if you dismiss and perform segue at the same time.

Comment: That means I should dismiss the modal view, which will result in view A being displayed and then I should push view b?

Comment: @ReadQ yes, in this way, user is also aware what is happening to the app so that when he presses back button in view B, he will not be confused why it is view A displayed instead of view D. That's my opinion though.